# "tcp session control protocol" in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm programming in Linux environment.

I want to establish a TCP socket between two PCs, and multiplexing it.

To be specific, here is the pseudo-code:

```
void func_in_process0()
{
    socket s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(s, "1.1.1.1", 8080);

    socket s1 = ADD_CHANNEL(s, 1);                    // key part
    SEND_FILE_DESCRIPTOR_TO_PROCESS(s1, process1);
    socket s2 = ADD_CHANNEL(s, 2);                    // key part
    SEND_FILE_DESCRIPTOR_TO_PROCESS(s2, process2);

    WAIT_FOR_PROCESS_TO_FINISH(process1);
    WAIT_FOR_PROCESS_TO_FINISH(process2);

    close(s);
}

void func_in_process1()
{
    socket s1 = GET_SOCKET_FROM_PROCESS0();

    send(s1, "abcdefg");
    close(s1);
}

void func_in_process2()
{
    socket s2 = GET_SOCKET_FROM_PROCESS0();

    send(s2, "abcdefg");
    close(s2);
}
```

The key part is how to implement function ADD_CHANNEL.

I found a document [TCP Session Control Protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP-NG/http-ng-scp.html) which provides exactly the function I want.
But I don't think it is implemented in Linux kernel.

I can implement this protocol in userspace, but variable "s1" and "s2" will not be file descriptor and can't be sent to other processses.

Edit:

1. process0, process1 and process2 are all on localhost.
2. socket "s" is a client socket.
3. 1.1.1.1 is a remote PC, who is the server. so proc1 and proc2 both sends packet to 1.1.1.1 through the CHANNEL.
4. the server is CHANNEL aware too.

Edit2:

1. I read the [SCP Protocol](http://www.ibiblio.org/ses/scp.html), but it still has no in-kernel implementation.
2. I learned the SCTP multi-streaming, which is implemented in kernel, but there's no API that creates sub-socket so the problem remains.

Comment: You want to establish a TCP session between a linux kernel driver(?) and some other machine... and all in kernel space? Why can't file descriptors be sent through ipc again?

Comment: Session Control Protocol was proposed as part of the HTTP-NG project in the late '90s, but was never really implemented. Some parts of it live on in [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol), but even that is considered quite experimental.

Comment: You want to have 3 processes communicating with a single TCP connection?  The first process runs on one machine and the other two on a second machine?  It would help to understand the use case - seems like there may be simpler ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: Looking at SCP (a protocol separate from TCP it seems), it looks like a hard solution to a simpler problem.  If startup and shutdown cost of a TCP session is significant, the server and client can use a single session to perform multiple operations.  In fact, that's what FTP does (mentioning FTP because it's called-out by that page on SCTP).

Comment: Yeah, we can use protocol other than TCP since the server and client a both developed by our team. I'll give SCP protocol a look.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, they can be file descriptors. Create two pipes and give one end to each of the other two processes. Your 'multiplexor' will read from, and write two, the other ends of the two bidirectional pipes.

Comment: Yeah it's a solution, but it brings unnecessary memory copies and user/kernel mode switches.

Comment: You can avoid the memory copies with sufficient cleverness. The user/kernel mode switches are necessary if the protocol is going to be implemented in user-space.

Comment: Do you mean the [splice() architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_(system_call))? I'll check it out.